# MongoDb count column value with multiple match condition

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

---

How to perform count on a particular column value with multiple match condition with aggregation.
How to count EmpId in DeptId 1 and TimeCode 22

- Empid DeptId TimeCode
- 1      1      22
- 2      1      25
- 3      1      22
- 4      2      22
- 5      1      21

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your problem with an example?

Comment: @DeepakPatankar : Already elborated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#Example in mongo to count number of employees in perticular department.

```js
db.getCollection("Employee").aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$match" : {
                "DeptId " : 1
            }
        },
        {
            "$match" : {
                "TimeCode" : 22
            }
        },
        {
            "$count" : "EmployeeId"
        }
    ],
    {
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
);
```